# Como mostrar un directorio de carpetas y subcarpetas de un sistema web

Tags: php

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en donde pueda ver un directorio desglosando Carpetas, Subcarpetas y Archivos.

a verdad estoy algo verde en esto de php, y no encontré ningún ejemplo de como mostrarlo

espero me puedan brindar algún ejemplo u orientación

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que el directorio está en la máquina que ejecuta el script PHP, puedes utilizar la función [scandir](http://php.net/manual/es/function.scandir.php).

```
array scandir ( string $directory [, int $sorting_order = SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING [, resource $context ]] )
```